# NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_RoutingModel'

Tags: python, django, routes, or-tools

I was making route optimiser a web app developed in django which was working fine but due to some changes in I guess I wreaked my code of rote optimiser.It is showing me following errors:

```
File "/home/chirag/chirag/smartlogistics/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.py", line 3191, in __init__
this = _pywrapcp.new_RoutingModel(*args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded 
function 'new_RoutingModel'.
 Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
operations_research::RoutingModel::RoutingModel(operations_research::RoutingIndexManager const &)
operations_research::RoutingModel::RoutingModel(operations_research::RoutingIndexManager const &,operations_research::RoutingModelParameters const &)
```

I was unable to figure the problem, I'm new in django. Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, you picked the 7.0 beta release, which breaks the API. 
Look at:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/master/ortools/constraint_solver/doc

And

https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/tag/v7.0-beta.1

Comment: Please note we should release 7.0 next week.